# Customize a navigation menu C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, navigation

Simple question but cant find any answers.

How do i make my navigation menu in my web app in C# look "cool". I can see how to edit it etc. But how do  get to customize it.

Do i need to get another program or something ?

Comment: This question is too broad as perception of cool is subjective and 'or something' is a gateway to eternity.

Comment: Client comes to me and says, "I want a cool looking website" and leaves... all the developers have a laugh :D Couldn't find any cool menus, but here are some awesome ones :D http://www.webdesignerdepot.com/2013/11/25-awesome-responsive-menu-solutions/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You dont need any program. Its just html, css and javascript.